# Delete an Item in a list in SwiftUI by ID

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list that contains an item that is identifiable, how do I perform an manual on delete with the parameters is the id of the item??

View :

```
struct FavListView: View {
    @StateObject var favList = FavViewModel()
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(favList.items, id: \.self.id) { data in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: ItemDisplayVC(data.slug ?? "").navigationTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true),
                        label: {
                            ListContentItem(name: data.name ?? "", image: data.image ?? "", released: data.released ?? "", rank: data.rank ?? -1)
                        })
                }
                .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    print("\(indexSet)")
                })
            }
            .navigationTitle("Favourite")
            .onAppear {
                favList.fetchData()
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the model

```
public struct ItemPreviewModel: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int?
    var slug: String?
    var name: String?
    var image: String?
    var released: String?
    var desc: String?
    var rating: Float?
    var rank: Int?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, rating, released, id, slug
        case desc = "description_raw"
        case image = "background_image"
        case rank = "rating_top"
    }

}
```

Here's the manual func to delete the item in the database :

```
func onDelete(id:Int)  {
///perform delete by id
// refresh the view
}
```

are there any built in native func in swiftui that I could use? because I like the delete animation when you integrate it into a list.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Is this a SwiftUI question and if so where is the SwiftUI code?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add it

Comment: Your view shows the items in your view model `FavViewModel`. Thus, you implement `delete(id:)` in your view model.

Comment: i already did, i have built the onDelete func in my viewmodel

Comment: but, i want to use the built in animation of onDelete from ForEarch

Comment: You can use the `animation` modifier on your List: `.animation(.default, value: favList.items)`

Comment: how about the swipe to delete animation?

Comment: would it take alot of time if we built it manually?

Comment: These are all different questions. You can take a look into the Interweb and research a bit for yourself. There is plenty good stuff. Come back if you have a specific question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
List {
       ForEach(favList.items, id: \.self.id) { data in
           NavigationLink(
               destination: ItemDisplayVC(data.slug ?? "").navigationTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true),
               label: {
                   ListContentItem(name: data.name ?? "", image: data.image ?? "", released: data.released ?? "", rank: data.rank ?? -1)
               })
       }.onDelete(perform: deleteItemsId)
   }

    func deleteItemsId(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        for i in offsets.makeIterator() {
            let theItem = favList.items[i]
            // do your stuff with theItem.id
            // onDelete(id: theItem.id)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you, finaly. You really help me, like alot